# Отменить выполнение асинхронной функции C#

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте! Я реализовал данную форму. При клике на кнопку "Включить компьютер" у меня срабатывают следующие функции:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        instanceClass1.temperature = 19;
        label2.Text = "Включен";
        label4.Text = "Температура: " + instanceClass1.temperature + " °C";
        label5.Text = "Мощность: 700 Ватт в час";
        label7.Text = "выключена";
        button1.Text = "Компьютер в работе";
        if (_cts != null)
            return;
        try
        {
            using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                await ButtonFlashAsync(_cts.Token);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        _cts = null;

    }

    private async Task ButtonFlashAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        for (int i = 20; instanceClass1.temperature < 65; i++)
        {
            if (instanceClass1.temperature <= 45)
            {
                label4.Text = "Температура: " + instanceClass1.temperature + " °C";
                instanceClass1.temperature++;
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000, token);
            
        }
    }
```

Такой вопрос, как отменить асинхронную функцию при клике на вторую кнопку?

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        label4.Text = "Температура: нет данных";
        label5.Text = "Мощность: нет данных";
        _cts?.Cancel();
    }
```

Мне дали ответ про токен, однако ButtonFlashAsync не прерывается при нажатии на вторую кнопку.

Comment: Сколько еще вам надо закрыть вопросов, чтобы вы смогли скопировать код из уже существующего ответа?

Comment: `ButtonFlashAsync` не является асинхронным. Асинхронным метод делает не `async`, а `await`.

Comment: @aepot я сделал, как вы сказали, но почему у меня не прерывается при клике на вторую кнопку? См. код исправленный выше.

Comment: ButtonFlashAsync не прерывается при нажатии на вторую кнопку.

Comment: А где `await Task.Delay` вот вы токен отмены передали в метод, но его не используете никак. Где хоть один await в методе? Метод синхронный. Вы не сделали как я сказал.

Comment: Ещё `// ... ex.Message` замените на `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);`, а то не смешно даже, ловите исключение, но никак себе не даете понять, что поймали.

Comment: Перенесите всё из button2_Click кроме _cts?.Cancel() в самый конец button1_Click. Не надо изобретать

Comment: _Запомните 1 простую закономерность:_ если метод помечен как `async`, значит в нём **обязательно** должен быть как минимум 1 `await`. Просто как правило выучите себе.

Comment: @aepot спасибо вам ещё раз! Теперь точно всё сделал, всё работает.